# Do you know inheritance in createjs?

Tags: createjs

Anyone have any experience with inheritance and createjs. I am trying to extend the createjs.Container class with my button class but I am getting the following error in my browser console. Eveything seems to be working fine which makes me think the problem must be when the page loads. I have played around with the order that I load my scripts but it still produces the error. Below is the structure of my class.

TypeError: this.Container_constructor is not a function

```
 (function() {
    function Button(bmp, w, h) {
         this.Container_constructor();
         this.setup();
     }
     var p = createjs.extend(Button, createjs.Container);

     p.setup = function() {
          //code here
     } ;

 window.Button = createjs.promote(Button, "Container");
 }());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further poking around the problem is actually in my StartBtn class that extends my Button class. This is my working version.

```
(function() {
     function StartButton(bmp, w, h) {
         this.Container_constructor();
         this.bmp = bmp;
         this.width = w;
         this.height = h;
         this.setup();
     }
     var p = createjs.extend(StartButton, Button);

 window.StartButton = createjs.promote(StartButton, "Button");
 }());
```

Then just instantiate the StartButton and add it to the stage.

```
 this.startBtn = new StartButton(loader.getResult('btn_start'), 227, 50);
 this.addChild(this.startBtn)
```